# Where does eclipse keep its ANT classpath

Tags: eclipse, ant, configuration-files

I know I can look at the Preferences dialog box, but when comparing a broken build with a working one I would like to diff the files.

So where does eclipse keep its ant settings stored. I am specifically interested in the global settings.

Running Eclipse Version: Indigo Release Build id: 20110615-0604

Comment: I ran across this when I was searching for where eclipse kept the actual ant install. For me, this was `C:\Users\<User>\Documents\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_X.X.X\bin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is

workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime.settings\org.eclipse.ant.core.prefs

Answer (score 0):

Look into your `workspace\.metadata` directory and search for `*.launch`. These are the launch configurations including ant.

Comment: That is specific launches. I don't see the base ant configuration stored in preferences there.

Answer (score 0):

Launch configurations (including those for Ant) can be kept in the workspace by selecting "Save as - Shared File" in the "Common" tab in the launch configuration editor.